# equivalent in Groovy for Javascript's map()?

Tags: javascript, list, groovy, loops

In Javascript the function

```
array.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. (Per documentation on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).
Is there something equivalent in Groovy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`collect`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
def numbers = [1,2,3]
assert numbers.collect { it * 2 } == [2,4,6]
```

There are also variants defined specifically for `Collection` and array types (as opposed to collect itself which is valid for any object, with the default behaviour treating an arbitrary object the same as a single-element array containing just that object), such as [`collectMany`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectMany%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), which allows you to return a list of zero, one or more than one result for each element, with the results all concatenated

```
assert numbers.collectMany { (it > 1) ? [it, -1*it] : [] } == [2, -2, 3, -3]
```